# How to host HTML node.js application

Tags: node.js, hosting, socket.io

i have developed a simple webapp using socket.io and node.js and was wondering how i would deploy it to a server? My application uses an HTML file with a canvas element the user interacts with how would i deploy this, the css and the js files and the app.js file to the server?

thanks

Comment: Which server? Have you registered for an account with a hosting provider?

Comment: No, i havent registered for an account on any yet. Im am wondering because the ones i have looked at like appfrog only talk about the server.js file and i cant see anywhere to host my html or css files etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some hosting companies that support Node.js (like Nodejitsu and Heroku) you can deploy your static files as part of your application code. In other words, when you deploy your app both your code and static files (JS/CSS/Images) will be deployed.

The  downside with this approach is that you cannot easily just change a CSS file like you can in a more traditional deployment where you can just FTP a new CSS file to the production server. You could bypass this if you host your CSS files somewhere else, though.

I don't have experience with AppFog but I suspect the same is true.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 90 day free trial at Azure. Believe it or not but they have great support for node.js. Read more at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/